# CSS: Have floating children react before floating parents on shrinking window

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

I have two floating divs with display:inline-block and width:auto ("adapt to content"). Inside the second div, there are two floating child divs. Is it possible to sort of specify the "floating order" such that the child divs will react to a shrinking browser window before the parents do using CSS?(see attached image). Thanks for any suggestions!
[image]

Comment: You need to set the breakpoints with your media queries. P.s: adding the relevant css and the html markup is a plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. As others have mentioned you may need media queries to fine tune this.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/BuGcT/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.box1
{
    width: 48%;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 10px 30px 0;
    min-width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.box2
{
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-width: 120px;

}
.box
{
    background: aqua;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I had the second box (.box2) set to float:left. Once I removed it, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Media queries for that purpose.

You can reffer this for that

1) [Media_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

2) [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Thank you, great references. I will use them for further development as the layout will become more complicated and media queries seem just the thing I need for that!